# Android NDK and functional (std::function) support

Tags: android, c++, c++11, stl, android-ndk

I tried to use std::function in my project, having read here and there that C++ 11 is quite well supported. However simply using std::function makes the build fail:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: MyAppNative <= MyAppNative.cpp
jni/MyAppNative.cpp: In function 'jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)':
jni/MyAppNative.cpp:7:2: error: 'function' is not a member of 'std'
  std::function<void()> func;
  ^
jni/MyAppNative.cpp:7:24: error: 'func' was not declared in this scope
  std::function<void()> func;
                        ^
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/MyAppNative/MyAppNative.o] Error 1
```

My question is: is std::function supposed to be supported? I've seen it conditionally defined in the header, depending on _STLP_USE_BOOST_SUPPORT. Is that normal? I have attached a sample project if anyone is interested in testing.

http://www.filedropper.com/cpp11-functional-issue

Cheers

Comment: You do add the `-std=c++11` flag when building? Which version of GCC is used?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html at "How to set your runtime".

Comment: Yes I did add the flag (you can take a look at the archive), the GCC version is 4.8 I think (it was at least, before I updated to r10e for testing).

Christian> Thanks, but std::function is nowhere to be mentioned here. I'm using APP_STL := stlport_static already (in my downloadable sample), and nothing indicates that this version is downgraded.

Comment: @Brunni: Why downgraded? AFAIK STLport has never had C++11 support.

Comment: **[Christian Hackl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3313064/christian-hackl)** is right, you need **gnustl_static** or **c++_static**

Comment: I meant downgraded in that it supports less functionality compared to the others.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, could you please post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STLport, which you seem to be using, has never had C++11 support.

See [developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html) at *"How to set your runtime"* and choose a different one (gnustl_static or c++_static).

Comment: It would be better to copy paste how to configure the runtime instead of linking to an external size. Like Brunni did, his answer helped me much faster.

Comment: My Application.mk APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_CFLAGS += -std=c++11
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
APP_ABI := all
APP_MODULES :=ndksampleapp
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9 but still I am getting error 'std::function' has not been declared

Comment: Is it like stoi I will be able to get through c++_static and function through gnustl_static, coz if I replace with gnustl it is crying for stoi. I am new to this. This can sound silly or wrong question to some people. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so thanks to Christian and Alex, the answer is indeed to change your Application.mk so that it references gnustl_static.

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Thank you all!

Comment: The unwritten rules of SO courtesy would suggest that you let **[Christian Hackl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3313064/christian-hackl)** to post his comment as answer.

Comment: Yup I'm not used to it yet, but it clearly felt wrong :) Well for now I'll just cancel the answer mark and validate it when Christian Hackl posts an answer to this topic!

Comment: @Brunni: No problem. I did not realise that my comment would actually help you so much that you'd consider it an answer :) I've turned it into an actual answer now.